# Explicit type casting in js

Tags: javascript, types, casting

Is there a generic way to explicitly cast a variable to a specific type?
For example:

```
var b = true;
var str = "";
var n = 5;
cast(someVariable, typeof b);   //someVariable become a boolean
cast(someVariable, typeof str); //someVariable become a string
cast(someVariable, typeof n);   //someVariable become an integer
```

where a `cast` is supposed to be that magic casting method.

That's obvious that I can just enumerate in a `switch` all possible types. But is there a [beautiful] native way to do that?

Comment: Can't you use something like `Boolean( someVariable ), Number( someVariable );` ?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I can, but the thing is I don't always know the type of second argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using mapping:

```
var castMap  = {
    "boolean" : Boolean
};
var b = true;
var someVariable = "true";
castMap[typeof(b)](someVariable)
```

Comment: yeah, that looks more simple than switch operator. Thank you

Comment: This isn't a good answer.  `Number(val)` doesn't cast types like in c.